# Calculating Convolution Only for a Certain Interval Using "conv()" in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, continuous-data, convolution

Below you can see the code for convolution of two continuous functions. There is a function called `fx` which I took as the square root of a Gaussian distribution. The convolution is calculated using 2 methods. In one of them I use the built-in function `conv()` and in the other I use the definition of the convolution. In `mat_conv1` and `cont_conv1` the function `fx` is convolved with itself using the built-in and explicit calculation methods respectively. In `mat_conv2` and `cont_conv2` the two functions `mat_conv1` and `cont_conv1` are convolved with themselves using their respective methods. You can see the code below.

```
clear all
clc

a = 0;
b = 1;
c1 = 0.1;
c2 = 0.2;
d1 = 0.3;
d2 = 0.4;
ymin = -2;
ymax = 2;
ynum = 400;
ylist = linspace(ymin,ymax,ynum);

conv_1 = mat_conv2(ylist,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b);
conv_2 = cont_conv2(ylist,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b);

hold on
plot(ylist,conv_1,'DisplayName','conv()');
plot(ylist,conv_2','DisplayName','continuous');
legend('-DynamicLegend');

function res = fx(x,a,b)
res = sqrt(normpdf(x,a,b));
end

function res = mat_conv1(y,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);

gx_1 = fx(y/c1,a,b);
gx_2 = fx(y/c2,a,b);

res = (1/(c1*c2))*conv(gx_1,gx_2,'same')*dy;
end

function res = mat_conv2(y,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);

hx_1 = mat_conv1(y/d1,c1,c2,a,b);
hx_2 = mat_conv1(y/d2,c1,c2,a,b);

res = (1/(d1*d2))*conv(hx_1,hx_2,'same')*dy;
end


function res = cont_conv1(y,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);
xx = -2:0.01:2;

for i=1:length(y)

    gx_1 = fx(xx/c1,a,b);
    gx_2 = fx((y(i)-xx)/c2,a,b);
    yy = gx_1.*gx_2;
    yy = trapz(xx,yy);
    yy = (1/(c1*c2))*yy;
    res(i) = yy;

end
end

function res = cont_conv2(y,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);
xx = -2:0.01:2;

for i=1:length(y)

    hx_1 = cont_conv1(xx/d1,c1,c2,a,b);
    hx_2 = cont_conv1((y(i)-xx)/d2,c1,c2,a,b);
    yy = hx_1.*hx_2;
    yy = trapz(xx,yy);
    yy = (1/(d1*d2))*yy;
    res(i) = yy;

end
end
```

As you can see from the figure below the results match pretty neatly.

[image]

Now I only want to consider the positive domain. In other words, I want to take the convolution in the interval [0,2]. So I change `ymin` to zero and inside the functions `cont_conv1` and `cont_conv2` I start the vector `xx` from zero. The code is:

```
clear all
clc

a = 0;
b = 1;
c1 = 0.1;
c2 = 0.2;
d1 = 0.3;
d2 = 0.4;
ymin = 0;
ymax = 2;
ynum = 400;
ylist = linspace(ymin,ymax,ynum);

conv_1 = mat_conv2(ylist,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b);
conv_2 = cont_conv2(ylist,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b);

hold on
plot(ylist,conv_1,'DisplayName','conv()');
plot(ylist,conv_2','DisplayName','continuous');
legend('-DynamicLegend');

function res = fx(x,a,b)
res = sqrt(normpdf(x,a,b));
end

function res = mat_conv1(y,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);

gx_1 = fx(y/c1,a,b);
gx_2 = fx(y/c2,a,b);

res = (1/(c1*c2))*conv(gx_1,gx_2,'same')*dy;
end

function res = mat_conv2(y,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);

hx_1 = mat_conv1(y/d1,c1,c2,a,b);
hx_2 = mat_conv1(y/d2,c1,c2,a,b);

res = (1/(d1*d2))*conv(hx_1,hx_2,'same')*dy;
end


function res = cont_conv1(y,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);
xx = 0:0.01:2;

for i=1:length(y)

    gx_1 = fx(xx/c1,a,b);
    gx_2 = fx((y(i)-xx)/c2,a,b);
    yy = gx_1.*gx_2;
    yy = trapz(xx,yy);
    yy = (1/(c1*c2))*yy;
    res(i) = yy;

end
end

function res = cont_conv2(y,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);
xx = 0:0.01:2;

for i=1:length(y)

    hx_1 = cont_conv1(xx/d1,c1,c2,a,b);
    hx_2 = cont_conv1((y(i)-xx)/d2,c1,c2,a,b);
    yy = hx_1.*hx_2;
    yy = trapz(xx,yy);
    yy = (1/(d1*d2))*yy;
    res(i) = yy;

end
end
```

The result is given below.

[image]

As you can see the results are completely different. What am I doing wrong? How can I get rid of this discrepancy and use `conv()` to convolve the two functions in the positive domain?

Comment: This would get better answers at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Initially I asked this question at stackoverflow.com. There, they suggested me to post the question here. Now you advise me to ask it at dsp.stackexchange.com. My question is, is it OK to ask the same question in multiple stackexchange platforms?

Comment: personally, I would delete it from here and stack overflow and post it at dsp.stackexchange.com, since that is where it will most likely be answered.